# Chrome loading pages very slow

Tags: google-chrome, html

After I use chrome for some while, I find it pretty slow when loading URL pages. It maybe stuck somewhere when displaying pages.

[image]

I do not know why it is stuck. As you can see in the figure, it takes more than 5 seconds to load the Google.com page. When I use IE browser, it displays very quickly, less than 1 second.

Can anyone help me? Each time I have to uninstall Chrome and install it again to avoid this issue. But this issue always appears some time later. I am using Chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit) on Windows 7.